# How to develop Monitoring Website, technical analyse

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, http, monitoring

I have a special question well I need to know technologies behind monitoring website like **pingdom.com**

What is the beneficial language to use to develop this platform ? what library we can use ? What about distributed solution ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more of an opinion than a question (which is why it's received negative votes). This type of service could be developed in many languages. It's based on a few key principals.

- Can the site be reached? Yes/No
- What determined that the site could not be reached? Did it timeout?
- What is the max timeout that we will allow before we decide its unreachable?
- How does the site fair from other sources, worldwide, well we'll need to run the same code from multiple servers, and know where they are. This could be done with something like amazon which lets you set them up from all over the world.
- How does this fair compared to the last time we pinged it? (we'll need to store the result in a database for reference and feedback to the user)

You could easily make this sort of service in something like PHP, but like I said, it could be made in many languages, hence why this is an opinion as theres no real clear answer to this.

The biggest problem a site like pingdom.com has has
- Number of requests (they use a queuing system to stop their servers being overloaded)
- They make cash by monitoring sites all the time. So they need to make sure the value add revenue generated outweighs the cost of free users (leads they generate), which it clearly would, as they are so cheap.

Hope this helps.